# Microdoft ODBC for oracle defined source not being picked up by application and throwing SQLConnect() failed

Tags: oracle, odbc, exe

I have a 32 bit .net exe (on a win 7 machine) which runs and writes data to an oracle db. For this application to access the DB I have created a ODBC source (Microsoft ODBC for Oracle) under System DSN of odbcad32.exe from c:\windows\syswow64.

Instead of picking this source the application is picking a default connection source for the user. Please see below. (from sqlnet.ORA)
Fatal NI connect error 12560, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=BEQ)(PROGRAM=oracle)(ARGV0=oracleORCL)(ARGS='(DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))'))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ORCL)(CID=(PROGRAM=D:\Projects\abc\Web\dll\reader.exe)(HOST=abc-43DGMX1)(USER=NGolia))))

The application (exe) is obviously not able to connect to the correct DB and throws a 
ERROR   SQLConnect() Failed.

Could anyone help let me know what could be missing? Am I missing any environment variables or

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to test the connection in the Oracle ODBC Driver Configuration? If the application is 32bit, you're using the correct odbcad32.exe. I would check your tnsnames.ora in your $ORACLE_HOME and verify the database information looks correct there.

Comment: i HAVE INSTALLED ORACLE 11.2.0 CLIENT AND my oracle_home = D:\app\NGolia\product\11.2.0
tnsnames.ora
STIMMAPD =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 143.128.50.31)(PORT = 1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVICE_NAME = stimmapdb)
)
)

Comment: Also what should I put un the Server field on the microsoft odbc under system DSN.. I am assuming it is 143.128.50.31. Please let me know

Comment: Also, do any other oracle variables need to be set? the db details look correct.

Comment: Also, could there be a version mismatch?
I have installed ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit.

Comment: @nick What you probably need to do is re-run the Oracle Universal Installer and install the Oracle ODBC driver. Your driver should look like this: [link](http://oi40.tinypic.com/ev82hl.jpg). There is no server information to enter if you're using the Oracle ODBC Driver. All of that is derived from your sqlnet.ora -> tnsnames.ora which looks correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply kyle! The drivers looks similar to the image in the link but I need to use Microsoft odBC for Oracle for my exe.